# Grep router ARP-Table from client system without login router homepage using python

Tags: python, networking

sorry for poor english, :(

I need to extract ARP-TABLE from router and collect all IP and MAC address. but one condition without login router homepage. 
I tried `requests` module in python but router ARP-TABLE is dynamic so i can't get any data.

Comment: The problem is not with your English (I am not a native English speaker either...). The problem is that you do not show how that table could be extracter from the router (I assume that it depends on the router), nor what you have tried, so I cannot guess,  hence I cannot help :-(

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes you correct. it depends on the router. I tried with `requests` module with python to grep the table like request.get('192.168.43.1') like this but there is no DATA available it only shows table tags only. Because ARP-TABLE update via ajax in webpage. so i don't know how to collect that dynamic table data.

Comment: Still not enough info for me to answer. If you can get some data from a browser, you should use the development mode on that browser to see the exact request and responses that are exchanged. Then in Python you could try to send the exact same request and hope getting the expected responses.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes. I got that answer.  i monitor the request and response and get the solution. Thank you so much.